# Send and receive Datatable using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a model inside another model like:

First Model:

```
public class ReminderPushNotificationTest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ....
    public ReminderPushNotificationTableType AndroidResultTableType { get; set; }
}
```

Second Model:

```
public class ReminderPushNotificationTableType
{
    public string Headers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In SQL I create a table valued parameter and receive it as a parameter in my stored procedure as:

```
 @AndroidResultTableType [HELPER].[PushNotificationTestTableType] READONLY
```

I use Dapper to send the result as:

```
public async Task<bool> ReminderPushNotificationInsert_Test(ReminderPushNotificationTest model)
{
    try
    {
        async Task<bool> DoReminderPushNotificationInsert_Test()
        {
            using var connection = _connectionManager.GetOpenConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString));

            await connection.QueryAsync("[Test].[usp_spName]", param: new {
                model.UserId,
                model.AndroidResultTableType
            }
            , commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            return true;
        }
        return await DoReminderPushNotificationInsert_Test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception:

> The member AndroidResultTableType of type
>   Models.Helpers.Test.ReminderPushNotificationTableType
>   cannot be used as a parameter value

How can I pass `AndroidResultTableType` as datatable if is not a list. It always has 1 row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing direct object you need to construct DataTable and fill its fields

```
await connection.QueryAsync("[Test].[usp_spName]", new
{
    model.UserId,
    AndroidResultTableType = CreateTableType(model.AndroidResultTableType)
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

private static DataTable CreateTableType(
    ReminderPushNotificationTableType notification)
{
    var t = new DataTable();
    t.SetTypeName("[HELPER].[PushNotificationTestTableType]");
    t.Columns.Add("Headers");
    t.Rows.Add(notification.Headers);
    return t;
}
```